# How to find the nth digit of number 1 to n?

Tags: c

For example when the input is 25, the output must be 7 (the 25th digit of number 12345678910111213141516171819202122232425)

How can I solve this problem in C?

Comment: You can solve it with code. Post yours and explain specifically which portion is not functioning the way you expect.

Comment: This can be written in 2 lines, you need to know about arrays and strings. Is this homeworsk ? Do you know the C language, or not at all ?

Comment: Hint - array indexing may help.  Without any attempted code though, we don't know how input/output is supposed to be handled so we have no idea how to work with your list of numbers.

Comment: `int wantednumber = "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425"[input];`. Actually one line is enough.

Comment: @MichaelWalz - while that will work, it is something that will get him in big trouble with professor and you know it...  Still, I give you props for it.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan yes you are right, but he should know that too.

Comment: Perhaps a pedantic point, but lets substitute 3 for n. How do you propose to find the 3rd digit of the number 3?

Comment: Mahdi, you should change the title to something like *"how to find the n'th digit"*, and then explain in the question body that you are looking for the n'th digit in the sequence consisiting of positive integers concatenated without separators. You see, I suspect the question has been downvoted by those who didn't understand the question.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Off by one... should be `int wantednumber = "012345678910111213141516171819202122232425"[input];` since C arrays start at index 0, but the sequence starts at index 1. Or, `int wantednumber = "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425"[input-1];` if you prefer that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As usual, there is a simple answer, and a complex answer.

The simple answer has already been described by [Clifford](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40289558/1475978) in another answer: Construct the sequence of numbers as a string, then pick the `i`'th character from it.

The complex answer is much more interesting. The string is actually the OEIS sequence [A007376](http://oeis.org/A007376). There are known formulas (via related sequence A033307), but they are either geared towards producing the entire sequence, or contain nasty stuff like [the principal value of the Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Since the sequence is rather simple, we can construct our own algorithm.

Let's look at the sequence itself:

- First 9 digits are the digits themselves: 1, 2, 3, .., 8, 9
- Next 2*9*10 = 180 digits are from the numbers 10, 11, .., 98, 99
- Next 3*9*10*10 = 2700 digits are from the numbers 100, 101, .., 998, 999
- Next 4*9*10*10*10 = 36000 digits are from the numbers 1000, 1001, .., 9998, 9999

Let's call the part of the sequence that is formed from numbers with the same number of digits, a *region*. The first region contains the 9 single digits, the next the 180 digits from numbers 10 to 99, the next 2700 from numbers 100 to 999, and so on.

The key is to find the correct *region* for the index we are interested in. That turns out to be easy: We just subtract the number of digits in each region, until the "leftover index" is within the current region!

Let's say `n` is the number of digits in the correct region, with `i` being the "leftover index", the number of digits in smaller regions substracted from the sequence index.

To get the target number -- the integer value the sequence index picks the digit from --, we need to add 10<sup>n-1</sup> to `(i-1)/n`. This is because the first (so i=1) two-digit number is 10, not 11. The position in the number is `(i-1)%n` (the remainder of the division (i-1)%n), with 0 indicating leftmost. Another way to calculate the position is using `(n-1)-(i-1)%n`, with which 0 refers to the rightmost digit ("ones").

(As usual, the math becomes a bit simpler if you decrement the index by one earlier on, and use zero-based calculations.)

No need to take my word for it. Consider the following implementation:

```
#include <stdint.h>

const uint64_t pow_10[20] = {
    UINT64_C(1),
    UINT64_C(10),
    UINT64_C(100),
    UINT64_C(1000),
    UINT64_C(10000),
    UINT64_C(100000),
    UINT64_C(1000000),
    UINT64_C(10000000),
    UINT64_C(100000000),
    UINT64_C(1000000000),
    UINT64_C(10000000000),
    UINT64_C(100000000000),
    UINT64_C(1000000000000),
    UINT64_C(10000000000000),
    UINT64_C(100000000000000),
    UINT64_C(1000000000000000),
    UINT64_C(10000000000000000),
    UINT64_C(100000000000000000),
    UINT64_C(1000000000000000000),
    UINT64_C(10000000000000000000)
};

int A007376(uint64_t i)
{
    uint64_t     digits = 1U;
    uint64_t     value  = 1U;
    uint64_t     limit  = 9U;
    unsigned int tens;

    /* The sequence starts at index 1. Shift to zero. */
    if (!i--)
        return 0;

    /* Find the number of digits in each number
       in the region of index i. */
    while (i/limit >= digits) {
        const uint64_t old_limit = limit;

        i -= digits * limit;

        digits++;
        value *= 10U;
        limit *= 10U;

        /* If limit overflows, we are in the correct, final region. */
        if (limit <= old_limit)
            break;
    }

    /* We know the desired digit is i'th digit
       in a string formed by concatenating the
       9*10^(digits-1) numbers starting at 10^(digits-1).
       The value of this number is pow10(digits-1) + i/digits: */
    value += i / digits;

#ifdef DEBUG_OUTPUT
    fprintf(stderr, "Digit %d of %" PRIu64 " ", 1 + (int)(i % digits), value);
#endif

    /* Move the desired digit into the ones position. */
    value /= pow_10[(digits - 1) - (i % digits)];

#ifdef DEBUG_OUTPUT
    fprintf(stderr, "= %d\n", (int)(value % 10U));
#endif

    return value % 10U;
}
```

The above function provides the desired digit in logarithmic time complexity (O(log N)). Some interesting results:

```
i             A007376(i)

1             1

9             9

10            1
11            0

12            1
13            1

186           9
187           8

188           9
189           9

190           1
191           0
192           0

2884          9
2885          9
2886          8

2890          1
2891          0
2892          0
2893          0

4294967284    4
4294967285    8
4294967286    9
4294967287    5
4294967288    6
4294967289    4
4294967290    2
4294967291    6
4294967292    6

4294967295    9

18446744073709551580    1
18446744073709551581    0
18446744073709551582    2
18446744073709551583    9
18446744073709551584    3
18446744073709551585    6
18446744073709551586    0
18446744073709551587    7
18446744073709551588    9
18446744073709551589    9
18446744073709551590    2
18446744073709551591    0
18446744073709551592    1
18446744073709551593    0
18446744073709551594    8
18446744073709551595    7
18446744073709551596    5
18446744073709551597    1
18446744073709551598    0

18446744073709551615    5
```

Of course, there are many possible intermediate implementations between the 'simple' (sequence of numbers as a string, the pick the `i`th character from it) and 'complex' (the function, above), depending on how deep into the behaviour of the sequence you delve into.

Personally, I'd say that for this particular sequence, the *region* concept or similar, is a watershed. (You could, for example, just print the 64-bit target value in a buffer, and return the digit by picking it out from the buffer. I'd still put such an implementation to the 'complex' category.)

The simple method is useful as an exercise in string operations, perhaps even in dynamic memory management, but practical solutions in combinatorics and sequence-related problems should use the 'complex' approach if at all possible: the simple approach just [does not scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability).

Answer (score 3):

The first problem you will have is representing the number.  Even an unsigned 64 bit integer is good for only 19 decimal digits - i.e. log10( 2<sup>64</sup>).

So in this case your "number" must be entered and stored as a string; in that case it is just a case of indexing the string:

```
int digit_value = number_string[n-1] - '0' ;
```